Handling shared state in pytest fixtures with different scope
I'm facing an issue with pytest where tests are interfering with each other due to the shared state in a fixture with different scopes (function, class, session).
I've created a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the problem:
import pytest

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    
    def increment(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def counter_fixture():
    """Fixture with session scope."""
    return Counter()

class TestCounterIncrement:
    def test_increment_once(self, counter_fixture):
        assert counter_fixture.increment() == 1

    def test_increment_twice(self, counter_fixture):
        assert counter_fixture.increment() == 2

class TestCounterValue:
    def test_counter_value(self, counter_fixture):
        # This test will fail if it's not the first test executed
        assert counter_fixture.count == 0

In the example above, the Counter instance is shared across tests because of the session scope, leading to dependent tests.
If the scope="session":
The fixture will be shared among the two test classes and the test_counter_value test will fail and the TestCounterIncrement class will pass all his tests. Because the class TestCounterIncrement will be instantiated first, the Counter will no longer be zero.
======================================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================================
FAILED tests/MRE.py::TestCounterValue::test_counter_value - assert 2 == 0
================================================================================ 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 warnings in 0.13s ================================================================================

On the other hand, if the scope="class", all the test will pass. Because the state of the fixture will evolve correctly for each test class.
===================================================================================== 3 passed, 3 warnings in 0.01s =====================================================================================

Finally, with scope="function", in the TestCounterValue class, the Counter will be reset to zero for test test_increment_twice, causing the test to fail. Otherwise, the remaining tests will pass.
======================================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================================
FAILED tests/MRE.py::TestCounterIncrement::test_increment_twice - assert 1 == 2
================================================================================ 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 warnings in 0.13s ================================================================================

I'm looking for best practices or design patterns to handle such situations where tests need to share some resources but should remain independent in terms of state. Should I use a function scope for all fixtures, or is there a more nuanced approach to manage shared resources while keeping test independence?

It is generally not a good idea to change global state in a shared fixture, e.g. the problem is Counter.increment which changes the state of the global Counter instance unpredictably (for the test). If you need different states of Counter, you should make different instances of it, instead of changing one global instance. Depending on your actual use case, this may be done by using function-scoped fixtures, several session-scoped fixtures, or a parametrized session-scoped fixture.
